# Change float format in django, decimal separate by ( , ) and thousands by (.)

Tags: django, django-settings

I'm trying to change the format of the money representation in my django system. I use float to represent it. An actually a price look like this $1,500.30 and now I want to look like this $1.500,30

Here is the price in my model

```
public_price = models.FloatField
(
    verbose_name=_('Precio'),
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    default=0.0
)
```

Please help, any idea will be excellent.

Comment: Do you want to store the price comma format or you just want to show it like that on template level?

Comment: if isn't very difficult I prefer to store the price comma format.
Thank u so much